# Why $.each works but arr.each does not

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you guys explain me why `$.each` works but `arr.each` do not? This is my case:

```
$('.btnbtnbtn').on('click', function () {
    var pesho = {
        name: "pesho",
        value: 23
    };
    var gosho = {
        name: "gosho",
        value: 25
    };
    var arr = [pesho, gosho] ;    

    $.each(arr, function (key, value) {
        console.log(value.name, value.value)
    });
    return false;
});
```

This is the working example but if I replace `$.each` with `arr.each(function...)` it doesn't work.
I thought it to be the same thing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `each` is not valid javascript function. Its `forEach` . https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp

Comment: `arr.each` doesn't work as `arr` is not  a jQuery object

Comment: Thank you very much! It is clear now!

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, You should start suggesting MDN [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of _w3schools.com_

Comment: @Satpal: True. Noted... thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already said, the correct implementations are :

- `$.each` ([more info here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/))
- `arr.forEach` ([more info here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp))

Here is a working example of how to use properly each of them:

```js
var pesho = {
  name: "pesho",
  value: 23
};

var gosho = {
  name: "gosho",
  value: 25
};

var arr = [pesho, gosho];

$.each(arr, function(key, value) {
  $("#jQueryEach").append("<div>" + value.name + ": " + value.value + "</div>");
});

arr.forEach(function(item, key) {
  $("#jsArrayforEach").append("<div>" + item.name + ": " + item.value + "</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span>jQuery Each:</span>
  <div id="jQueryEach">
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <span>Javascript Array forEach:</span>
  <div id="jsArrayforEach">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's native arrays do not have an **each** function, but there's a [foreach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp) function that does same thing as JQuery's **each**

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "each" in native JS.

`forEach` can be used to iterate over an array.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

This does essentially the same thing as the first signature of jQuery's `$.each` (`jQuery.each( array, callback )`).
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Note that `jQuery.each()` can also be used to iterate over the properties objects (`jQuery.each( object, callback )` instead of over arrays. In this case the callback has a slightly different signature. The native JS equivalent of this type of loop would be `for...in` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score -1):

each() is a jquery function which works with only jquery objects, to make arr.each() as workable please convert the arr into Jquery object, replace arr.each() to $(arr).each(function.....), it should work

Hope it would help you

Comment: No. $(arr).each would assume that arr was a selector or list of HTML elements, in order for it to be made into a jQuery object. You mean $.each - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ which works directly on a normal array, not http://api.jquery.com/each/ which works on jQuery objects. Converting it to a jQuery object first here does not work and makes no logical sense when a better method already exists.